# Ruby refinements not working in CI server

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-2.0

I'm having errors within the Jenkins server:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
```

When running rspec, I have the following error:

```
 undefined method `using' for #<Class:0x000000026f9c88> (NoMethodError)
```

the exact same code works on my local computer, with ruby2. 
Here's my version: `ruby 2.0.0dev (2012-12-01 trunk 38126) [x86_64-linux]`
Also, it works on irb. It seems that ruby isn't recognizing the `using` statement when running a script.

Here's the code:

```
describe "blah" do
    include TestHelper
    using TestHelper::BrowserRefinement
    ...
end
```

---

clarification: **the refinement is defined in a different file.** I'm scourging the interwebs to see if there's a difference between revisions `r39474` and `r38126`.

Comment: if you insert `puts RUBY_VERSION`, what will RSpec print?

Comment: It shows the proper version:  2.0.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In current release of Ruby 2.0 (2.0.0p0), `using` is an instance method of the top-level object `main`, not that of `Module`. And it's a private method. If you call it in class/module definition or method definition, a RuntimeError is raised.

"The scope of a refinement activated by `main.using` is from the point just after `main.using` is invoked to the end of the file where `main.using` is invoked. However, when `main.using` is invoked in a string given as the first argument of `Kernel#eval`, `Kernel#instance_eval`, or `Module#module_eval`, the end of the scope is the end of the string."

You can read more about this in [Refinements Specification](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/RefinementsSpec).

For your test cases, you can write them with `eval` and pass in the top level bindings, like the [test cases](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-200/repository/entry/test/ruby/test_refinement.rb) in ruby source.

**Refinements is still an experimental feature, it may change in future :-)**

Comment: FYI, this has been changed in Ruby 2.1, `using` can be used even in `Module` (and hence a `Class` as well).